# Hard drive further partioning

Tags: hard-drive

i am using Ubuntu 16.04.before i was using windows 8.1.i installed Ubuntu and now only one partition appearing, with 804 GB free and 119 gb used total 923gb.kindly how i partition my hard-drive

Answer (score 2):

If you have a GUI installation then one of the easiest way to format drives is using Gparted.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

It's possible that you've installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1, in which case the other 804GB may still be in use by Windows.

If this is the case, but you want to use the entire drive, then you have two options:

1. You can re-install Ubuntu entirely and erase the entire drive during the setup. This will allow you to have one big partition, which is easiest to manage.
2. You can format the extra space with GParted and mount it as an additional storage location by going to File Explorer -> Other Locations and accessing the partition there.